# How to remove only numbers from a string in Pandas columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm an environmental geologist and I'm just learning Python/Pandas. I have a dataframe of analytical data in Pandas similar to the example below:

[image: starting dataframe]

I only want to remove numbers from Total_dl leaving the detection limits (numbers with <). This would be the final dataframe I'm looking for:

[image: final dataframe I'm looking for]

Since the column is strings I'm not sure how to parse the column. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `Total_dll`? Also, I would advise you to copy and paste the dataframes here instead of posting them as pictures/links.

Comment: Helpful.. but still not cut-n-pasteable

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The type of Total_dl is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it. Not sure how good a solution it is:

```
df['Total_dl'] = df['Total_dl'].apply(lambda o: o if '<' in str(o) else np.nan)
```

Using a function that does the same instead:

```
>>> df
   SampleID Total_dl
0    A-1-0'      2.5
1  A-1-0.5'   <0.021
>>> df.dtypes
SampleID    object
Total_dl    object
dtype: object
>>> def foo(o):
...     if '<' in str(o):
...         return o
...     else:
...         return np.nan
...         
>>> df['Total_dl'] = df['Total_dl'].apply(foo)
>>> df
   SampleID Total_dl
0    A-1-0'      NaN
1  A-1-0.5'   <0.021
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Todd. I tried the your first solution and it did the trick. Going to try the function as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np


mask = df.Total_dll < 1.
df.loc[mask, 'Total_dll'] = np.nan
```

---

If `Total_dll` is of type `string` you can try the following:

```
import numpy as np


df.str.startswith('<')
df.loc[df.Total_dll.str.startswith('<'), np.nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your data frame is called `df`, then this will do the trick

```
import numpy as np
nan_condition = df[~df["Total_dl"].str.contains(">")]
df.loc[nan_condition,"Total_dl"] = np.nan
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
data = data.loc[data[column] > x]
```